# Launch Front End from .NET MathKernel and return result to .NET

Tags: front-end, kernel, interoperability, windows, .netlink

Is it possible to launch a front end and open a notebook from a .NETLink kernel and return a result from the notebook to .NET?

In the code below "x" appears in the .NET textbox after 10 seconds but the notebook in which its value could be changed doesn't appear.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Wolfram.NETLink;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MathKernel kernel = new MathKernel();
            kernel.Compute("Needs[\"JLink`\"];");
            kernel.Compute("$FrontEndLaunchCommand = \"Mathematica.exe\";");
            kernel.Compute("UseFrontEnd[nb = NotebookOpen[\"exists.nb\", Visible->True];");
            kernel.Compute("Pause[10];");
            kernel.Compute("CloseFrontEnd[];");
            kernel.Compute("x");
            this.textBox1.Text = kernel.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Alternatively, is it possible to identify the .NETLink kernel so that a notebook could sent it information via the `Evaluator` option?

According to *MathLink - Network Programming* (p. 217) it looks like it should be possible:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With a lot of help from this answer: [Connect Frontend to Kernel Started by JVM via JLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56248/363)

here is a demo that opens a notebook from .NET (via button1), allows the user to make a dynamic manipulation, and then sends the result back to .Net where it is displayed in the form.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Wolfram.NETLink;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MathKernel kernel = new MathKernel();
            kernel.Compute("linkName = \"Bob\"");
            kernel.Compute("remoteLinkObj = LinkOpen[linkName, LinkMode -> Listen]");

            kernel.Compute("Needs[\"JLink`\"]");
            kernel.Compute("$FrontEndLaunchCommand = \"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\7.0\\Mathematica.exe\"");
            kernel.Compute("UseFrontEnd[nb = CreateDocument[Null, Visible -> False]; NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[{RowBox[{RowBox[{\"linkName\", \"=\", \"\\\"Bob\\\"\"}], \";\"}], \" \", RowBox[{RowBox[{\"feLinkObject\", \"=\", RowBox[{\"LinkOpen\", \"[\", RowBox[{\"linkName\", \",\", RowBox[{\"LinkMode\", \"\\[Rule]\", \"Connect\"}]}], \"]\"}]}], \";\"}], \" \", RowBox[{RowBox[{\"SetAttributes\", \"[\", RowBox[{\"remoteEval\", \",\", \"HoldRest\"}], \"]\"}], \";\"}], \" \", RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{\"remoteEval\", \"[\", RowBox[{\"link_LinkObject\", \",\", \"expr_\"}], \"]\"}], \":=\", RowBox[{\"(\", RowBox[{RowBox[{\"LinkWrite\", \"[\", RowBox[{\"link\", \",\", RowBox[{\"Unevaluated\", \"[\", \"expr\", \"]\"}]}], \"]\"}], \";\", RowBox[{\"LinkRead\", \"[\", \"link\", \"]\"}]}], \")\"}]}], \";\"}]}], \"Input\"]]; SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]; SelectionEvaluate[nb];  NotebookClose[nb]]");

            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\front end side.nb");

            kernel.Compute("evalLoop[link_LinkObject] := Module[{resultOfEval, exprIn, exprOut, evalMessages}, evalMessages = {}; collectMessages[m_] := AppendTo[evalMessages, m]; Internal`AddHandler[\"Message\", collectMessages]; While[True, evalMessages = {}; exprIn = LinkRead[link, Hold]; resultOfEval = Check[exprOut = ReleaseHold[exprIn], $Failed]; Which[resultOfEval === $Failed, LinkWrite[link, EvalError[\"In\" -> exprIn, \"Out\" -> exprOut, \"Messages\" -> evalMessages]], True, LinkWrite[link, exprOut]]]; Internal`RemoveHandler[\"Message\", collectMessages]; LinkWrite[link, \"Evaluation loop is off\"]]");
            kernel.Compute("evalLoop[remoteLinkObj]");
            kernel.Compute("x");
            this.textBox1.Text = kernel.Result.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```